# How to detect a letter position in a label and put an arrow to show it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a label in my view, and i would like to put an arrow just under this specific letter.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the size of a string for a given font.

```
NSString* labelString = @"cheese toast";
// Say you want the first 't'
NSString* stringUpToLetterPosition = @"cheese t";

NSDictionary* attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"** Name of Label's Font **", NSFontNameAttribute,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:aTextLayer.fontSize], NSFontSizeAttribute,
    nil];
NSAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringUpToLetterPosition attributes:attributes];
NSSize size = attributedString.size;
```

There will be an additional offset from the edge of the label, but that will vary depending on the distance of the edge of your label from the beginning of the label text. Just experiment until you find the right value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..this may help you.I am taking another lable as pointer.

```
CGSize size_txt_overview1;
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(180, 20000.0f);
for (int i=0; i< [_Heading_lbl.text length]; i++) {
    if ([Lbl_Heading.text characterAtIndex:i] == '8') { // i have taken 8 as my target charecter
        NSString *str = [Lbl_Heading.text substringToIndex:i];
        size_txt_overview1 = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:17] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        NSLog(@"%f",size_txt_overview1.width);
    }
}
Lbl_Arrow.frame = CGRectMake(SomeNum+size_txt_overview1.width, 140, 18, 21);//SomeNum is the X position of Your lable.
```

Answer (score 0):

UIKit has a category on NSString to get the size of a string with a specified font. Get the size of the full string, then a string up to the char of interest, then one including the char.

You can then find the location of the full string (left, right, or centered). The x position will be centered between the values of the two other partial strings.